# Can't use SQLite in Nativescript and external device SDK 25, Android 7.1.2

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nativescript

I have been trying to get Nativescript to work with SQLite and an external device I have running Nougat (7.1.2), SDK 25.

I get the following error:

`Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$OpenParams`

I have a class that extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper`

```js
class DatabaseHelper extends android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static constructorCalled: boolean = false;

    constructor(context: android.content.Context) {
        super(context, '/data/user/0/org.nativescript.synctest/databases/swiftr.sqlite', null, 2);
        DatabaseHelper.constructorCalled = true;

        return global.__native(this);
    }

    onCreate(db: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase) { }

    onUpdate(
        db: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,
        oldVersion: number,
        newVersion: number
    ) { }
}
```

I am trying to open the SQLite database like this:

```js
const mOpenHelper: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(application.android.context);

const sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type ='table' AND name NOT LIKE '%sqlite_%'";
const cursor = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

const tables: string[] = [];

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
        tables.push(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex('name')));
    }
}

console.log('Tables: ', [tables]);
```

Then when I try to use this class in a component, I get the error,
`Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$OpenParams`

I did a bit of digging and discovered that `SQLiteDatabase$OpenParams` was only added into the SDK in version 27. I then tried to set the `compileSdkVersion` in `app.gradle` to 25 and now I get the following errors:

app.gradle:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Errors:

`AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/forceDarkAllowed' not found.`

`AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.`

`AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.`

Here I have only listed three but there are many of them.

Could anyone please assist me with this issue... I am really struggling to get it resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the compile SDK version, it has to be Android Q with latest version of NativeScript (6.x).

Also you can not use a API that's not available in your device. If your device is running Android 7.x, you can not use an API method that is actually introduced only on Android 8.x (API level 27).

If you are intended to use an API that may not be available in one of the OS version your app supports, then you should run it conditionally. Here you will check if the platform version is >= 27 and run the specific code.

Comment: How would I use the SQLite 3.9 API in NativeScript? The device will always use Nougat 7.1.2 but NS is using the API for SQLite version higher than is available? Is there some way I can force NS to use the 3.9 API of SQLite?

Comment: You must understand NS just a JavaScript runtime, all it does is the ability to program your native app in JavaScript. NS or even native Android app can not let you use an API that's not available in your device, at least until there is a support library.

Comment: Would it be possible to use something like `androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0-alpha01` to open a connection using the 25 SDK API?

Comment: Yes, you may use the support library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended solving this issue by using `SQLite Android Bindings`.

Check it out... https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki